# How to properly name the two types of RAM in a Paper?

Tags: terminology

How do I name VRAM and RAM properly in a paper?

"Video RAM" is clear but the "normal" RAM? Is it called "CPU RAM" or "Processor RAM" or "Main RAM" or totally different?

Comment: This may depend on the field. What field/topic would the paper be about, and do other papers in the field discuss these concepts?

Comment: I guess "Primary RAM" or "general purpose RAM"  would be suitable. But I an not sure myself.

Comment: It should probably be "eponymous RAM". Like the "eponymous Pentium processor" is the ancient Pentium processor that Intel built before they added new versions that needed individual names, or the "eponymous iPhone" was built in 2007, before they had individual names.

Answer (score 2):

I have usually heard "main memory" for the CPU-accessible RAM.

Wikipedia calls it "[primary storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_data_storage#Primary_storage)", with "main memory" listed as a synonym. Although honestly, I would have guessed that "primary storage" referred to the primary nonvolatile medium (SSD or HDD).

Comment: "Primary memory" in the [memory hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy) is the memory that code and data are stored in for direct use. "Primary *storage*" is somewhat misleading, yes - I'd use "storage" for secondary and tertiary (backup) memory only.